# How to import ICS file in Android Google Calendar app?

Tags: android, import, calendar, icalendar

I have ICS file and i want to import this ics file or through internet ics file into my Android Google calendar. I could not find option of import file and add URL like we have in google calendar desktop version

Comment: From what I understand, this question is not about programming. Probably it will be better addressed in [Android Enthusiasts site](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to import ICS (file or URL) is by the website: Settings > Import & Export or Settings > Add a calendar > Using an URL